# Select by Expression and Extract by Expression generate different results

Tags: qgis-3, extract

I have a polygon layer and want to extract all Polygons with the field "street" = 1.

When I use "Select by Expression" I get the following correct result:

[image]

However, when I use "Extract by Expression" I get the following wrong results:

[image]

When I look into the attribute table of the extracted layer all values under the field "street" = 1 but a couple of them shouldn't be.

What could be the problem?

I'm using QGIS 3.10

Comment: Which values do the additional extracted polygons have? Also consider making a bug report.

Comment: In the original layer, the additional extracted polygons have the value 0. After "Exctract by expression" they have the value 1 all of the sudden.

Comment: have tried to use qgis 3.14? does the same problem occru with this latest release too?

Comment: You may have double polygons. You don't see all of them when use select by extraction, but extract by expression creates a new layer. Check the attribute table after Select by expression or export selection to a new layer.

Comment: What about other attributes? Are they the proper ones or does it look like the attributes of another polygon? I have seen this kind of mismatch with data stored in a DB with duplicated IDs (user's fault), and also when doing changing shape type in a virtual layer (likely a bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the original vector layer and now it works. Unfortunately I haven't figured out where the problem was since I think I did the layer the same as before but extract by expression gives me now the correct results.